# Submit text from a contenteditable div via jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, submit

I want to submit text from a div, while preventing a browser reload. I did read the jQuery documentation, but I couldnt figure this out, so I would greatly appreciate some specific instruction.

My form is styled to display: none. 
This is where I gave up. Not sure if I'm even on the right track:

```
$('.focus').click(function() {
    var str = $(".focus").text(function(){
        $.post('/main', $(".focus_form").serialize( str ));
    });
});
```

Thank you

To resolve the problem, I set the val of the input. Thought I would post this incase another noob lands here with a similar situation.

```
var str = $(".focus").text();
$('.focus_input').val( str );
$.post("/main", $(".focus_form").serialize());
alert( str );
```

Comment: try changing `$.post('/main', $(".focus_form").serialize( str ));` to `$.post('/main', $(".focus_form").serialize( str ), function(data){console.log(data);});` and you'll be able to see what it's outputting, that would be a good start.

Comment: Well I broke it down to debug, while putting it back together I realized I could just set the val of input, so I did that.